# "Is" operator gives me False, Can I know the reason, why?

Tags: excel, vba

When writing MS Excel VBA code I met a simple question, like this.

The upper one has no problem at all.

The lower one has a problem.
It gave me "False".

```
Dim my01, my02
Set my01 = Sheets(1)
Set my02 = Sheets(1)
MsgBox my01 Is my02

Set my01 = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
Set my02 = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
MsgBox my01 Is my02
```

I expected that it shows "True".

[EDIT]
I have tried "=" operator and found that it works well. Though, it does not give any light into my question.

Comment: change `Is` to `=` in the second part.

Comment: @Bradipo - that answers an entirely different question.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, Yes I have saw it too, some hours ago. And.. I guessed that "the same instance of an object" means in my case, "Set my** = Sheets(1).Range("BulahBulah")". So, it ("Is") has to to emit "True".. Right ?

Comment: @오바마 - you've used `Range` twice, so you've got two different object references.

Comment: so.. You are saying, the exact point when the "Instanciation" is not "Set" command but "Range" command. OK.. Have to think about it. Thanks Lot.

Comment: One option might be to check that the parent of both is the same, and then check that their addresses are the same.

Comment: interesting.. what's parent to "Range("A1")" ?

Comment: If you change each of your `MsgBox` lines to `Debug.Print my01 Is my02, ObjPtr(my01), ObjPtr(my02)` then you will see the object references for the Worksheets are the same but for the Ranges they are not hence the result from `Is` ...

Comment: @BigBen that sounds strange. Yes the parent(s, both of them are same) and their address are same again. So, that means Could I expect to have "True" ? or not ?

Comment: Yes, you'll get `True`. See the last line of my edited answer (may need to refresh the page). Note that you're using `Is` at the sheet level (no problem), and `=` for the addresses (again, no problem).

Comment: Sheets(1) (and all others) have existing references as the codename ie Sheet1 so you are effectively doing `Set my01 = Sheet1 :   Set my02 = Sheet1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482718/is-operator-does-not-return-true-for-two-range-variables-that-point-to-the-sam#comment45288771_28482718):

> The `Range` property always returns a new object reference even if you are referring to the same cell. (well, it will re-use previous references if they are not currently pointed to by a variable) - Rory, Feb 12, 2015 at 17:01

This can easily be verified using `ObjPtr`:

```
Dim my01, my02
Set my01 = Sheets(1)
Set my02 = Sheets(1)
    
Debug.Print ObjPtr(my01), ObjPtr(my02) ' Identical, e.g. 1134792280    1134792280 
Debug.Print my01 Is my02 ' True
    
Set my01 = Sheet1.Range("A1")
Set my02 = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    
Debug.Print ObjPtr(my01), ObjPtr(my02) ' Different!, e.g. 1091015848    1091023048 
Debug.Print my01 Is my02 ' False
```

The linked thread proposes comparing their `.Address`. You could take it one step further and also compare their `.Parent` or `.Worksheet`.

```
Debug.Print my01.Worksheet Is my02.Worksheet And my01.Address = my02.Address ' True
```

Short cut solution by using the `external`-parameter

```
Debug.print my01.Address(external:=True) = my02.Address(external:=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have learned here one thing that "Range" property is quite difficult to use. Your explanations are perfect. Nice !!!

Comment: @오바마 - yes `Range` has a lot of intricacies. We haven't even touched on [default member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32997154/9245853)!

Comment: No need to compare worksheets, with `external:=True` the address will be distinct per each sheet and workbook: `Debug.print my01.Address(external:=True) = my02.Address(external:=True)`

Comment: It does work with unsaved workbook - that's where I tested it. :-)